# Algoritmo Flood Fill no funciona correctamente

Tags: java, algoritmos, matrices

Tengo problemas al implementar el algoritmo Flood Fill en Java, he visto ejemplos pero no me funciona del todo bien, no convierte todos los elementos, se supone que desde un punto central, tiene que ir creciendo mientras va cambiando los elementos que son iguales por el nuevo valor.

Tengo la siguiente matriz

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Aplico el algoritmo desde la columna 3 y fila 2 y al imprimir la matriz queda de la siguiente manera:

```
1 1 1 2 2 
1 1 1 2 2 
1 1 1 2 2 
1 1 1 2 2
```

Pero comenzando desde la posición `0,0` este funciona correctamente.

```
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2
```

Parece que funciona bien avanzando en filas de arriba hacia abajo y viceversa, pero en las columnas que seria `x-1`, no funciona, solo en `x+1`.

Este es el código del algoritmo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
private static void floodFill(int[][] array, int x, int y, int newValue) {
    int value = array[x][y];
    
    if(value != newValue) {
        replace(array, x, y, value, newValue);
    }
    
}

private static void replace(int[][] array, int x, int y, int value, int newValue) {
    if(x < 0 || x >= array.length || y < 0 || y >= array[0].length || array[x][y] != value) {
        return;
    }
    
    array[x][y] = newValue;
    
    replace(array, x + 1, y, value, newValue);
    replace(array, x - 1, y, value, newValue);
    replace(array, x, y + 1, value, newValue);
    replace(array, x - 1, y, value, newValue);
}
```

Y el método main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = {{1,1,1,1,1},
                     {1,1,1,1,1},
                     {1,1,1,1,1},
                     {1,1,1,1,1}};
    
    floodFill(array, 0, 0, 2);
    
    printArray(array);
}

private static void printArray(int[][] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución al problema, tenia los parámetros de la recursión mal, también tuve que cambiar los nombre que le había puesto x e y, porque ya me estaban confundiendo, ahora r y c, son filas y columnas.

Primero se va hacia la arriba `r-1` (fila - 1), luego hacia la izquierda `c-1` (columna - 1), después hacia abajo `r+1` (fila + 1) y por ultimo hacia la derecha `c+1` (columna + 1), o al menos así funciona aquí.

```
replace(array, r - 1, c, value, newValue);
replace(array, r, c - 1, value, newValue);
replace(array, r + 1, c, value, newValue);
replace(array, r, c + 1, value, newValue);
```

El algoritmo Flood Fill quedaría de esta forma:

```
private static void floodFill(int[][] array, int c, int r, int newValue) {
    int value = array[r][c];
    
    if(value != newValue) {
        replace(array, r, c, value, newValue);
    }
    
}

private static void replace(int[][] array, int r, int c, int value, int newValue) {
    if(r < 0 || r >= array.length || c < 0 || c >= array[0].length || array[r][c] != value) {
        return;
    }
    
    array[r][c] = newValue;
    
    replace(array, r - 1, c, value, newValue);
    replace(array, r, c - 1, value, newValue);
    replace(array, r + 1, c, value, newValue);
    replace(array, r, c + 1, value, newValue);
}
```

Funciona correctamente incluso con "caminos"

```
1 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 1 1
0,0 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Queda así:

```
1 1 2 2 2 1 
1 1 2 1 2 1 
2 1 2 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 1 2 
1 1 1 2 1 2 
1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Hice un ejemplo y aplique este algoritmo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]